# Rails -v on different projects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

if I´m working on a couple of rails projects and each needs a different version, do I have to reinstall the version required or the version is individual for each project?. Thanks

Comment: This is exactly what [bundler](http://bundler.io) is for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Rails versions for multiple projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672531/multiple-rails-versions-for-multiple-projects)

Answer (score 2):

The version should be specified in the `Gemfile` of each project, eg:

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
```

Then, you should prefix commands with `bundle exec` - eg. `bundle exec rails server`, and bundler will ensure that the appropriate version of rails is used, as specified in your `Gemfile`.

(The same goes for all other gems in your Gemfile by the way. So bundle exec basically says "ignore any other gems that may be installed on this computer - just create an environment with the specific gems specified in my Gemfile")

So, coming back to your question, the version is specified for each individual project - you don't have to re-install it per-se, but that's only because bundler will handle all the installing of different versions for you, behind the scenes.

Want to learn more? Check out this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GvFfd_MCJq0 and the related blog post version: http://andre.arko.net/2015/04/28/how-does-bundler-work-anyway/